# Odoo Float field Rounding

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

I am using Odoo 10 and I cant figure out how to stop a custom float field rounding.

Here is my field `box = fields.Float("Yards Per Box")`

In Odoo if I put 1.196 into the field it auto rounds to 1.20 how can I stop this on  a custom Float field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the suggested answers worked. I got it working by using  dp.get_precision

here is an example

```
cost_price = fields.Float(
 'Book Cost', dp.get_precision('Book Price'))
```

Then setting Book Price in deciaml accuracy under technical to 3

This is a better way of doing it than hard coding as I can change the decimals to any figure from Odoo GUI under **Technical | Database Structure | Decimal Accuracy**

Comment: You can also use digits=(16,3) instead of dp.get_precision method. But with dp.get_precision you can change easily the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
box = fields.Float("Yards Per Box", digits=None)
```

Comment: Adding box = fields.Float("Yards Per Box", digits=None) does not work

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

box = fields.Float("Yards Per Box", digits=3)

if you want to add 3 digit precision...